# Jerky effect while toggling the content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to show or hide the content upon button click. But I get this jerky effect while doing so. Can some one let me know if there's any problem in constructing markup. Also is it possible to give a smooth toggle effect while toggling.

[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/soujanyaj27/rue2e2cu/1/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#anchor-1").click(function () {
    if ($('#pre-1:visible').length)
      $('#pre-1').hide();
    else
      $('#pre-1').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <h4>Heading 4</h4>
      <h5>Heading 5</h5>
      <h6>Heading 6</h6>
      <a href="javascript:;" id="anchor-1">Show code</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <pre id="pre-1" class="text-left rad-0 text-danger hide">
      "<h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <h4>Heading 4</h4>
      <h5>Heading 5</h5>
      <h6>Heading 6</h6>"
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you define 'jerky effect'? When clicking show code, it appears to stay perfectly in place for me, adding the new content below. If the code is partially visible when clicking 'close', it jumps to the bottom of the visible content, as I would expect.

Comment: Can you please check the code that I mentioned in the link, The markup jumps when we do hide or show.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ Check my answer below its one line solution no need to change html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes to html:-

1. Put both 'col-md-12' within the 'row'
2. Add `style="display: none"` to the hidden content (inline styling is not ideal but bootstrap stops jQuery showing the content if 'hidden' is used). Remove `.hide { display: none; }`
3. Change the code within `<pre>` to have `&lt;` and `&gt;`

So:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <h2>Heading 2</h2>
            <h3>Heading 3</h3>
            <h4>Heading 4</h4>
            <h5>Heading 5</h5>
            <h6>Heading 6</h6>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="anchor-1">Show code</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <pre id="pre-1" class="text-left rad-0 text-danger" style="display: none">
&lt;h1&gt;Heading 1&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;h2&gt;Heading 2&lt;/h2&gt;
&lt;h3&gt;Heading 3&lt;/h3&gt;
&lt;h4&gt;Heading 4&lt;/h4&gt;
&lt;h5&gt;Heading 5&lt;/h5&gt;
&lt;h6&gt;Heading 6&lt;/h6&gt;
            </pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changes to jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#anchor-1").click(function (e) {
        // Added
        e.preventDefault();
        // Changed
        if ($("#pre-1").is(":visible")) {
            // Use fadeOut() and fadeIn()
            $('#pre-1').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('#pre-1').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

Essentially, the fadeOut() and fadeIn() should smooth out the 'jerky' effect. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rue2e2cu/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#anchor-1").click(function () {
    if ($('#pre-1:visible').length)
      $('#pre-1').slideUp();
    else
      $('#pre-1').slideDown();
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <h4>Heading 4</h4>
      <h5>Heading 5</h5>
      <h6>Heading 6</h6>
      <a href="javascript:;" id="anchor-1">Show code</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <pre id="pre-1" class="text-left rad-0 text-danger hide">
        "<h1>Heading 1</h1>
        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
        <h4>Heading 4</h4>
        <h5>Heading 5</h5>
        <h6>Heading 6</h6>"
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've used `slideUp` & `slideDown` instead of `hide` & `show` respectively.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It works fine here in this editor, but when I apply it on a plain .html page or on jsfiddle the disturbance in the markup still persist while doing slide up or down.

Comment: @SoujanyaJ I've updated the answer, there is a small change in the HTML structure. All the `col` model should be inside a row.

Answer (score 0):

Its because of height.

Jquery has trouble getting the height because it is in hidden state so jquery its inherits default height.

When you toggle the anchor, because of its content height its toggling scrollbar. So if you add scrollbar by default your problem will be solved.

In your case,

**Solution 1 :**

Simply enable scrollbar by default as

```
 html{overflow-y: scroll;}
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rue2e2cu/6/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#anchor-1").click(function () {
            if ($('#pre-1:visible').length)
                $('#pre-1').hide();
            else
                $('#pre-1').show();
        });
    });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

html{overflow-y: scroll;}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        
        
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <h4>Heading 4</h4>
      <h5>Heading 5</h5>
      <h6>Heading 6</h6>
      <a href="javascript:;" id="anchor-1">Show code</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <pre id="pre-1" class="text-left rad-0 text-danger hide">
                    "<h1>Heading 1</h1>
                        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                        <h4>Heading 4</h4>
                        <h5>Heading 5</h5>
                        <h6>Heading 6</h6>"
            </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution 2 :**

wrap container with a parent div and add height to it(or add directly to container) to enable scrollbar so its something like

```
.parent{height:101vh;}
```

and working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rue2e2cu/4/

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#anchor-1").click(function () {
            if ($('#pre-1:visible').length)
                $('#pre-1').hide();
            else
                $('#pre-1').show();
        });
    });
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.parent{height:101vh;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <div class="parent">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <h2>Heading 2</h2>
      <h3>Heading 3</h3>
      <h4>Heading 4</h4>
      <h5>Heading 5</h5>
      <h6>Heading 6</h6>
      <a href="javascript:;" id="anchor-1">Show code</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <pre id="pre-1" class="text-left rad-0 text-danger hide">
                    "<h1>Heading 1</h1>
                        <h2>Heading 2</h2>
                        <h3>Heading 3</h3>
                        <h4>Heading 4</h4>
                        <h5>Heading 5</h5>
                        <h6>Heading 6</h6>"
            </pre>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```